# apply alternate style sheet to handheld, not working right

Tags: css, html, mobile

I have two style sheets for one page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lsharecomplete_mob.css" media="handheld" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lsharecomplete_dt.css" type="text/css" media="Screen" />
```

I am testing on android and Iphone, and both seem to be picking up the "screen" style. 
Is it better to use @media in one style sheet instead of using alternate sheets or am I doing something wrong.

I have checked the link and server directories to make sure the files existed and where linked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone's Mobile Safari doesn't consider itself of the "handheld" media type.

> iOS ignores print and handheld media queries because these types do not supply high-end web content. Therefore, use the screen media type query for iOS.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW2).

Instead, use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: That did it, for both devices.. should i keep the "handheld" type for all others or just rely on the max-device-width?

Comment: @DanielHunter: I wouldn't bother with it myself, if you are only targeting iPhones & Android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the handheld style AFTER your standard style. Otherwise everything from your mobile design will be overwritten.