# CSS Media query for mobile phone not detecting screen width?

Tags: css

Here is the CSS:

> ```
> header {
>   width: 400px;
>   margin: 0 auto;
> }
> section {
>   width: 400px;
>   margin: 0 auto;
> }
> footer {
>   width: 400px;
>   margin: 0 auto;
> }
> ```

Here is the query on index.html that I have:

> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />`

It looks correct, but I could be wrong.

Comment: What phone are you targeting? Alot dont see themselves as handheld devices. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147635/apply-alternate-style-sheet-to-handheld-not-working-right

Comment: I have an Kyocera Rise android 4.0 phone, but I want all smartphones to display the mobile style. This style was JUST created so that's why there is almost nothing on it.

Comment: Tried screen width media queries instead? I know they work on a lot of the smart phones. A lot more then `media=handheld`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most smartphones can be targeted by using css media queries. And as an advantage you can also target small browser windows. 
Have look at [www.lessframework.com](http://www.lessframework.com) there is explained what these queries do, and how you can adopt is.

Comment: For tablets, I have min and max width, but for phones I just have a little under the width average smartphones have for more universal compatibility. But for phones I have what's shown above.

Comment: You can set your min-width as high or as low as you want, if you want you can even make multiple styles for smaller and or wider phones. (I'd only change body width then)

Comment: Most smartphones have at least 400 pixels for their screens, I believe so that should suffice for most smartphones, plus a tablet view, and a desktop view. This is for my website I'm redesigning.

Comment: media queries will allow you target them all individually. eg. 400+ for smartphones, 600+ for tablets, 960+ for desktops and 1200+ for widescreen monitors

Comment: I will work on that when I get the next chance too, I was previously at my web class at the local college, now I'm in my Office program. My laptop at home has a 1920x1080 resolution so I can do some testing on that as well.

Comment: I'm actually gonna test out the lessframework and see how it works, works on my devices (3.5" android average res phone), tablet (thing is, it has a 1080 screen), and desktop 1080 as well.

Comment: I am testing this currently, and I am trying to get the H1 to appear as it's normal size on a desktop/tablet, but bring it down to say 20px or around there for mobile phones. I am using the Lessframework with retina media query enabled although I don't have a retina device, I'd like to be able to support it.

Comment: Here is the CSS (i'm starting to use pastebin for larger chunks of code): http://pastebin.com/6GfrxaBx

Comment: Then you can can put it under the corresponding media tag and redefine it. `@media .. { H1 { ...} } `It should be asked as a different question though, since this one is answered.  That way we keep stackoverflow relevant.

Comment: Okay, Will do since I am still new. (I have browsed here for a while anonymously for finding answers but didnt register till recently).